Cannot connect to Cassandra 5.0 cluster with cqlsh, getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geomet'"
We are upgrade Cassandra Cluster from 4.1 to 5.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.9 (Ootpa).
After upgrade, we are trying to connect to instance but no successful.
follow the msg:
[root@SERVER01 cassandra]# cqlsh 10.134.67.65 9042 -u cassandra -p XPTO123
Warning: unsupported version of Python: 3.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 82, in <module>
    from cqlshlib.cqlshmain import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cqlshlib'
[root@adqtrjvhcsdr01 cassandra]#

We upgrade the python to 3.8 and Java to 17 .
After that, we unzip a new cqlsh ( 6.8)  but no success.
[root@SERVER01 bin]# ./cqlsh 10.134.67.65 9042 -u cassandra -p 123mudar 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh-6.8.43/bin/dsecqlsh.py", line 104, in <module>
    from dselib.geotypes import patch_import_conversion  # nopep8
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh-6.8.43/bin/../pylib/dselib/geotypes.py", line 10, in <module>
    from geomet import wkt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geomet'
[root@adqtrjvhcsdr01 bin]#

can you help us ?
[root@SERVER01  bin]# java --version 
openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.10.0.7-1) (build 17.0.10+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-17.0.10.0.7-1) (build 17.0.10+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
[root@SERVER01 bin]# python -V
Python 3.8.17


This line indicates to me that you have downloaded a version of cqlsh that's intended for DataStax Enterprise 6.8:
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh-6.8.43/bin/dsecqlsh.py", line 104, in <module>

cqlsh-6.8.43 requires the geomet module that is only used in DSE clusters.
You should use a version of cqlsh that is included with your version of Apache Cassandra. I recommend that you download the Cassandra 5.0 tarball, unzip it, then use the cqlsh included in the tarball. Cheers!
